# Why does the get request in jquery return an object, but the promise interface returns a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a bit confused about the $.get method in jQuery. When using the get method jQuery automatically parses the JSON as an object literal;

For example:

```
$ajax("exampleurl.php", function(data){console.log(data.propertyName)});
```

This returns the right key / value.

But when I use the promise interface it returns data as a string that needs to be parsed, for example:

```
$ajax("exampleurl.php").done(function(data){console.log(data)});
```

This will return [object, object]

Is there a reason that I'd have to parse the data returned via promise, whereas the callback function for the method does this for me automatically? It just seems a bit strange, so I was wondering if there is a reason for this.

Comment: I think you're mistaken; as far as I'm aware there is no difference in behaviour between AJAX callback functions bound at the time of the request vs. called later via `done()`. This has only to do with the request's data type and how jQuery infers that it should interpret it.

Comment: `This will return [object, object]`  Looks like it's returning an array, you might find you answer is in the first one.. eg.. `data[0]`   Promises are only meant to return 1 value, multiple values are often returned either inside an array, or an object literal.  I know from past jQuery was not Promise A+ spec compliant, maybe your running a version that is.. :)

Comment: @Keith Thank you, looks like the data was nested within an array - sorted